# Is F1-F12 the same for every keyboard/language

Tags: accessibility, keyboard

I have little tooltip graphics, each with a picture of a keyboard shortcut. Sometimes, the picture is a <kbd>F5</kbd>, a <kbd>F10</kbd>, etc.

I was wondering (for accessibility reasons) if everyone has a keyboard with "F" shortcuts. Maybe in some other language it's <kbd>C1</kbd>, <kbd>C2</kbd>, ..., <kbd>C12</kbd>.

What about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, etc. ?

Comment: I suggest you read about the difference between key-codes and char-codes. Not really a UX issue, btw.

Comment: I disagree: This is a UX issue. The question is basically: "Does displaying a specific piece of terminology negatively impact the usability of the site?" which is a valid question.

Comment: While I was studying abroad in Japan, I noticed that the `F1-12` keys were labeled as such. From some brief image searching on google, it seems that any keyboard that contains the function keys has them labeled as `f1-12`.

Comment: I read that you tag it as accessibility issue so I would ask to you a simple thing off-topic:
These images have the method Title in its <img> tag?
If not this is an issue for blind persons!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not really depending on the language layout, but more to the computer system you are using. Here's a list of computer systems and their relation to function keys:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_key

I think that on a regular Windows PC you can safely assume that the function keys are there.

Answer (score 3):

Function is such a common "international" word, that it's always begins with F, even in such a strange language, like Hungarian: it's *funkció*, where the accented *o* is a long o (ooh). Alt is the same story. Ctrl is also common, in Hungarian keyboard, it's Ctrl too, but Germans use *Strg* for Ctrl.